# Linear operator satisfy $\operatorname{dim}(ran(A)) \le \operatorname{dim}(ker(A)^{\perp})$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Is it true that for a general bounded linear operator we have $\operatorname{dim}(ran(A)) \le \operatorname{dim}(ker(A)^{\perp})$? On finite-dimensional spaces we clearly have equality from matrix theory, but is at least this relation true for arbitrary bounded operators on hilbert spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\ker(A)$ is closed, we have that

$$H= \ker(A) \oplus \ker(A)^{\perp}.$$

From this it follows that $A|_{\ker(A)^{\perp}}$ is one-to-one, and that its range coincides with the range of $A$. Therefore the dimension of the range of $A$ is **equal** to the dimension of $\ker(A)^{\perp}$ (in particular, either both are finite or both are infinite).